# Cookies don't work when using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, pickle

I tried to automatically log in with cookies. 
So I saved the cookies after I successfully logged in via my account. 
However, every time I try to read the file and add cookies to get the URL. It just directs me to that URL. The exit code will be 0.

I don't know why. Could you please help? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle

def save_cookies(driver,path):
    with open(path,'wb') as filehandler:
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(),filehandler)

def load_cookie(driver,path):
    with open(path,'rb') as cookiesfile:
        cookies=pickle.load(cookiesfile)
        for cookie in cookies:
            # del cookie['domain']
            print(cookie)
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://mail.qq.com/"
path="D:\\download\\test.txt"
browser.get(url)
load_cookie(browser,path)
time.sleep(2)
browser.get(url)
print(browser.get_cookies)
```

The cookies will be like when I print the cookie from the cookies:

```
{'expiry': 2147385600, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'pgv_pvi', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '82039xxx'}
{'expiry': 1536315518, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'ptui_loginuin', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '441984694@qq.com'}
{'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'pgv_si', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 's6206319xxx'}
{'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'ptisp', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'cm'}
```

I tried to print the cookies at the end of the code, but it seems it can't be added. Why? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use chrome options user-data-dir for this. The cookies are always stored and can be used from there. This method is faster than doing by code.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.protonmail.com")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works for me! May I ask why I cannot manually add the cookies? It may not be convenient for others to use as you need to add your own data path as "user-data-dir".

Comment: Cookies work in a per session basis. So if you quit your session, its gone. This can be overrriden by using user-data-dir as an argument and further name it accordingly. You can then refer to this directory to access your previous cookies. Great to know it worked for you. You may accept the answer so others can locate it if they run into similar questions.

Comment: Do you mean that next time I open the session, my saved cookies won't work if I run the code like I mentioned before?.. Thanks for your help! I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Won't work if you run the code like before. The specific argument user-data-dir allows you to store the cookie data into what you mentioned in the argument. If you don't use it, chrome would look into default and over write it. But since you passed your specific user data directory, and named it something, chrome has to use it and not the default. I hope I am clear with my explanation.

Comment: I understand. As I began to learn the selenium and cookies, I read some code related to it. What is it used for if it doesn't work if I close the session? I hope I don't brother you too much..

Comment: If you close the session and you want to reuse the previous cookies, you can use the one from user-data-dir=selenium. When you mentioned add_argument, your driver session would understand it needs to read from the cookies kept in that directory. That way you can reuse the cookies. But if you do not use add_argument, driver will look into default and see its empty so it will create new cookies and that way you cannot use the old cookies. add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium') basically directs the driver to use the data dir as "selenium" and then it will pick previous cookies.