# I'm trying to parse my own journal from livejournal with Selenium and fail to login

Tags: python, selenium

First, I've tried to import cookies. So I logged in and copied the cookies into my code. It worked once! Then it stopped working and I don't get why. I've updated the cookies, it didn't help.

the code is the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

EXE_PATH = r'/Users/homefolder/chromedriver' 

driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(EXE_PATH)

out = open('output.txt', 'w')
next_url = 'https://myjournal.livejournal.com/'
record_counter = 0
driver.get(next_url)
cookies = (here are various cookies, I type them in manually)

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()

try:
    while record_counter < 5:

        dates = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'date-header')
        headers = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-header')
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-body")
        prev10 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'content-nav')
        link = prev10.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
        next_url = link.get_attribute('href')

        assert isinstance(elements, object)

        first_ten = zip(dates, headers, elements)

        for i in first_ten:
            i = map(lambda x: x.text, i)
            date, header, element = i

            out.write(date)
            out.write('\n')
            out.write(header)
            out.write('\n')
            out.write(element)
            out.write('\n\n')
        record_counter += 1

finally:
    driver.close()
    out.close()
```

This code doesn't login and copies only open posts. What can I do to log in?

I also tried this recommendation:
[Cookies don't work when using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745994/cookies-dont-work-when-using-selenium)
with the same result.

Comment: Finally, I've found the way to do it.